# Design Pattern for implementing erc721

Tags: erc-721

any example to apply some pattern to divide logic and data structures of a contract type erc721?

I have a contract that I am building that is at the limit, (a marketplace with auction)... I would like to have 3 contracts, one for the logic of the marketplace, another for the auction, and the main one on top of these...
question, I've been researching but I don't understand which is the best way to do it.
Whether to use library, or to make 3 contracts and import the 2 in the main one and instantiate them....

Which would be the best way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One main contract inherits everything. Other contracts provide functionality which is bite-sized.

Here is the first ERC-721 compliant contract. It was written to be an example of this kind of encapsulation you are asking about ~~ https://github.com/su-squares/ethereum-contract/tree/master/contracts